# Move Settings Tiles around in October CMS

Tags: octobercms

Some October CMS plugins create their own categories for the settings page. I have figured out how to rename them using my own language file:

**/app/lang/author/plugin/en/lang.php:**

```
<?php
use System\Classes\SettingsManager;

return [
    'settings' => [
        'category' => 'new name'
    ]
];
```

Using `SettingsManager::CATEGORY_CMS` instead of `new name` does not work and instead only prints the language string `system::lang.system.categories.cms`. Wrapping it in a `Lang::get()` only results in me now having two CMS categories.

Editing the plugin file directly and using `SettingsManager::CATEGORY_CMS` works fine and moves the tile into the CMS category.

I'd like to avoid editing the plugin file. Is there a way to sort settings tiles in October CMS?